# Unable to run Randoop on a maven project

Tags: java, maven, randoop

Im trying to run Randoop for a java application based out of Maven.
The project has been compiled successfully through cmd through

G:\javapplic\a12>mvn compile

The java files which I wanted to create test on  are present on :
G:\javapplic\a12\src\main\java\org\jaffa\datatypes\configurer

I used randoop to generate classes present inside the folder:
G:\javapplic\a12\target\classes\org\jaffa\datatypes\configurer

Therefore in cmd I used the following code to generate the test cases:

```
java -Xmx3000m -classpath G:\javapplic\a12\target\classes\org\jaffa\datatypes;G:\New\randoop-all-4.2.2.jar randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=org.jaffa.datatypes.configurer.MybatisConfigurer
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEthX.png)
This is the path of the classes present

SO after I run the above cmd command I get the following error:

```
    G:\javapplic\a12>java -Xmx3000m -classpath G:\javapplic\a12\target\classes\org\jaffa\datatypes;G:\New\randoop-all-4.2.2.jar randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=org.jaffa.datatypes.configurer.MybatisConfigurer
Randoop for Java version "4.2.2, branch master, commit 4f20da2, 2020-02-29".
Unable to load class "org.jaffa.datatypes.configurer.MybatisConfigurer" due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jaffa.datatypes.configurer.MybatisConfigurerWill explore 0 out of 1 classes
There are no operations to test. Exiting.
Model with hashcode 1846896625:
  classTypes = [java.lang.Object]
  inputTypes = []
  coveredClassesGoal = []
  classLiteralMap = {}
  annotatedTestValues = []
  contracts = ContractSet[size=12]
  arity 1: [randoop.contract.EqualsReflexive@5cb9f472, randoop.contract.EqualsToNullRetFalse@cb644e, randoop.contract.EqualsReturnsNormally@13805618, randoop.contract.CompareToReflexive@56ef9176, randoop.contract.SizeToArrayLength@4566e5bd]
  arity 2: [randoop.contract.EqualsSymmetric@1ed4004b, randoop.contract.EqualsHashcode@ff5b51f, randoop.contract.CompareToAntiSymmetric@25bbe1b6, randoop.contract.CompareToEquals@5702b3b1]
  arity 3: [randoop.contract.EqualsTransitive@69ea3742, randoop.contract.CompareToSubs@4b952a2d, randoop.contract.CompareToTransitive@3159c4b8]

  omitMethods = [^org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.differentiation., ^org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.integration., \bensuresCapacity\b, ^com.google.common.collect.Iterators.cycle\(, ^org.apache.commons.math4.genetics.GeneticAlgorithm.getRandomGenerator\(\)$, ^org.apache.commons.math4.util.FastMath.random\(\)$, ^java\.util\.Date\.<init>\(\)$, ^java\.io\.File\.listFiles\(\)$, ^java\.io\.File\.listFiles\(java\.io\.FileFilter\)$, ^java\.io\.File\.listFiles\(java\.io\.FilenameFilter\)$, ^java\.io\.File\.listRoots\(\)$, ^java\.io\.File\.list\(\)$, ^java\.io\.File\.list\(java\.io\.FilenameFilter\)$, ^java\.lang\.Class\.getSigners\(\)$, ^java\.lang\.Object\.hashCode\(\)$, ^java\.lang\.String\.hashCode\(\)$, ^java\.lang\.System\.clearProperty\(java\.lang\.String\)$, ^java\.lang\.System\.console\(\)$, ^java\.lang\.System\.currentTimeMillis\(\)$, ^java\.lang\.System\.getProperties\(\)$, ^java\.lang\.System\.getProperty\(java\.lang\.String, java\.lang\.String\)$, ^java\.lang\.System\.getProperty\(java\.lang\.String\)$, ^java\.lang\.System\.getSecurityManager\(\)$, ^java\.lang\.System\.getenv\(\)$, ^java\.lang\.System\.getenv\(java\.lang\.String\)$, ^java\.lang\.System\.identityHashCode\(java\.lang\.Object\)$, ^java\.lang\.System\.inheritedChannel\(\)$, ^java\.lang\.System\.mapLibraryName\(java\.lang\.String\)$, ^java\.lang\.System\.nanoTime\(\)$, ^java\.lang\.System\.setProperty\(java\.lang\.String, java\.lang\.String\)$, ^java\.lang\.reflect\.Method\.hashCode\(\)$, ^java\.text\.BreakIterator\.getAvailableLocales\(\)$, ^java\.util\.AbstractList\.hashCode\(\)$, ^java\.util\.AbstractSet\.hashCode\(\)$, ^java\.util\.Arrays\.deepHashCode\(java\.lang\.Object\[\]\)$, ^java\.util\.Arrays\.hashCode\(boolean\[\]\)$, ^java\.util\.Arrays\.hashCode\(byte\[\]\)$, ^java\.util\.Arrays\.hashCode\(char\[\]\)$, ^java\.util\.Arrays\.hashCode\(double\[\]\)$, ^java\.util\.Arrays\.hashCode\(float\[\]\)$, ^java\.util\.Arrays\.hashCode\(int\[\]\)$, ^java\.util\.Arrays\.hashCode\(java\.lang\.Object\[\]\)$, ^java\.util\.Arrays\.hashCode\(long\[\]\)$, ^java\.util\.Arrays\.hashCode\(short\[\]\)$, ^java\.util\.Collection\.hashCode\(\)$, ^java\.util\.Collections\.shuffle\(java\.util\.List\)$, ^java\.util\.Comparator\.compare\(java\.lang\.Object, java\.lang\.Object\)$, ^java\.util\.List\.hashCode\(\)$, ^java\.util\.Random\.<init>\(\)$, ^java\.util\.Set\.hashCode\(\)$]
Operations:
  java.lang.Object.<init> : () -> java.lang.Object
```

So if anyone knows a workaround to make Randoop work on a maven project please do let me know

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an answer [here](https://github.com/randoop/randoop/issues/754).  I'll repeat the answer here, but in the future please ask your question to one forum at a time.

This question has nothing to do with Maven.

The answer to your question is in the log you provided.  You need to fix your classpath.

Your Randoop invocation specifies only one class to test:

`--testclass=org.jaffa.datatypes.configurer.MybatisConfigurer`

However, that class was not found on the classpath:

```
Unable to load class "org.jaffa.datatypes.configurer.MybatisConfigurer" due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jaffa.datatypes.configurer.MybatisConfigurer
```

Thus, Randoop tries to test 0 classes:

`Will explore 0 out of 1 classes`

It can't create tests for any of those 0 classes, so it exits:

`There are no operations to test. Exiting.`

If you fix your classpath, you will be able to run Randoop.